# Error C2512 when creating a std::promise<std::tuple<T>> (Visual Studio-only)

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I'm encountering an error (Visual Studio-only) when creating a `std::promise<std::tuple<T>>` whose type (`T`) has no default constructor.

I've created a derived example to highlight the issue.

```cpp
#include <future>
#include <tuple>

class Foo {
public:
    Foo() = delete;

    Foo(int value) :
        mValue{ value } {

    }

private:
    int mValue;
};

int main()
{
    std::promise<std::tuple<Foo>> p{};
}
```

```
1>------ Build started: Project: ConsoleApplication1, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>ConsoleApplication1.cpp
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\include\future(206): error C2512: 'std::tuple<Foo>::tuple': no appropriate default constructor available
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\include\future(203): message : while compiling class template member function 'std::_Associated_state<_Ty>::_Associated_state(std::_Deleter_base<_Ty> *)'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Ty=std::tuple<Foo>
1>        ]
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\include\future(1143): message : see reference to function template instantiation 'std::_Associated_state<_Ty>::_Associated_state(std::_Deleter_base<_Ty> *)' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Ty=std::tuple<Foo>
1>        ]
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\include\future(1143): message : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::_Associated_state<_Ty>' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Ty=std::tuple<Foo>
1>        ]
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\include\future(1143): message : while compiling class template member function 'std::promise<std::tuple<Foo>>::promise(void)'
1>C:\Users\Quenton Jones\source\repos\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1.cpp(22): message : see reference to function template instantiation 'std::promise<std::tuple<Foo>>::promise(void)' being compiled
1>C:\Users\Quenton Jones\source\repos\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1.cpp(22): message : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::promise<std::tuple<Foo>>' being compiled
1>Done building project "ConsoleApplication1.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

When compiling with clang, there's no issue.

Why is Visual Studio demanding that `T` have a default constructor?

Comment: [known issue](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/stdpromise-doesnt-support-types-that-are-not-defau/372171) - `We’ve investigated this issue and found that fixing it will break our ABI. To preserve binary compatibility, we don’t allow ABI breakages within the current release of the library.`

Answer (score 0):

To workaround this known issue, I've done the following:

```cpp
class Foo {
public:
#if _WIN32
    Foo() {
        throw std::exception("Invalid Constructor");
    }
#else
    Foo() = delete;
#endif

    Foo(int value) :
        mValue{ value } {

    }

private:
    int mValue;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

A common cause of error C2512 is when you define a class or struct constructor that takes arguments, and then you attempt to declare an instance of your class or struct without any arguments.For details, please refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-errors-2/compiler-error-c2512?view=msvc-160).

One more point, currently `std::promise` cannot be compiled with non-default constructible types.Using `#if`, `#else` is also a way.